# How would I go about knocking someone off my home internet?

Tags: networking, internet, blocking

Is there a way I can see who is accessing the internet on my network and block them?

I am connected through Ethernet and there are 2 laptops connecting though the network via wifi, and it is the wifi users I would like to block.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about a wireless network, or the answer should be obvious.  But what are the details?

Comment: I am connected through Ethernet and there are 2 laptops connecting though the network via wifi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess who is accessing is connecting with wi-fi so if you have a router, you could change the password to access the wi-fi. Additionally, you can enter in admin mode on the router, look at the machines connected, black list them or fix their IPs (giving allways the same one) and block the IPs in the firewall. These 1st steps will probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Blacklist it with [MAC Address Filtering](http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/wirelessproducts/qt/macaddress.htm)